# Insert text or Tags on Marked position

Tags: javascript, html

I´m currently working on a project were I need to add two HTML `tags` on a marked position.
So I created a `textarea` where you can write some text. After that I will mark it in this area. Now the user should be able to press a button which adds the pre defined tag at the beginning and end of this mark. This should work like in Stackoverflow.

EDIT: I tried it with this code to insert it at the cursor position what works quite well.

```js
function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);
  if (!txtarea) {
    return;
  }

  var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
  var strPos = 0;
  var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
    "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
  }

  var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
  var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
  txtarea.value = front + text + back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var ieRange = document.selection.createRange();
    ieRange.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    ieRange.moveStart('character', strPos);
    ieRange.moveEnd('character', 0);
    ieRange.select();
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
  }

  txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="infoid" name="info" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width:30%" type="text" ></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="insertAtCaret('infoid', '<b>');return false;">Click Here to Insert</a>
```

Are there any ideas how to mark it and put the tags before and after the marked position?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can not see your efforts. Share your source code whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. As mentioned above, I tried to code it only for this two functions. Sadly it didn´t work properly. So I´ve found an Open Source application. I downloaded it and have put it into the Project with the `<link>` and `<script>` Tag.
It´s called Summernote. You can find it [here](https://summernote.org/). 
With this code I was able to adapt it to this two options. It´s quite customable. Just look into the documentation.

Hopefully this will help someone a day.